# PHONEGAP " GPS AND INTERNET CHECK BEFORE IT GOES TO NEXT PAGE"

Tags: cordova

Hello guys this is gugan, Actually i am new to phonegap and i am creating a " Taxi driver App" i need a small help from you guys, if i open the app it need to check " whether internet and Gps connection is enabled or not " if it enabled it directly go next page or it need to show alert message please " Turn on Gps and intenet like " could any one please help me

Answer (score 0):

For internet connection use offline event as reported on cordova docs: [events offline](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.8.0/cordova/events/events.offline.html)

sample:

```
    document.addEventListener('offline', this.onOffline, false);
    ...
    onOffline: function (event) {
        window.location.replace('yourofflinepage.html');
    }
```

For gps connection install cordova geolocation plugin and check his geolocationError event: [cordova-plugin-geolocation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation)

> geolocationError: (Optional) The callback that executes if an error occurs.